# GWT setUrl function of Image class does not work in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, gwt, internet-explorer-8

Now i am using GWT ,  I am trying to change the image path, but it does not work in IE

I am displaying image using Base64 encoding ..it displays image properly but when i am trying to change the image to another Base64 encoding image it does not work in IE

Please suggest me

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the same URL, IE will cache that image. What you need to do is slightly change the URL like adding some query string behind it ... for instance:
http://localhost/mysite/image.jpg?**reload=1**

Or of course prevent the caching itself in the first place.

Comment: as i told u that i am displaying image using base64Encoding , so how can i append some slightly code the image url

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand ... the URL is probably not base64 encoded but the image itself. So change the URL as described and reload the image. Or have I missed something.